# Java anonymous function dependent on code in the calling method

Tags: java

I have a few methods that begin (let's call it block A) and end (block C) with identical code, only the code in the middle (block B) is different in each method. I would like to make a single method that somehow takes block B as an argument and executes it between blocks A and C. It could easily be done with an anonymous function, but the trouble is that block B is dependent on block A, and block C is dependent on block B.

Here's some fictional code that illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish (of course, the code doesn't compile):

```
public void method() {
    wrapper(new Function() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            // notice that variable x is defined in "wrapper"
            x += 1;
        }
    })
} 

public void wrapper(Function func) {
    int x = 5; // BLOCK A

    func.execute(); // BLOCK B, now x should be 6

    System.out.println(x) // BLOCK C
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Pass x as a parameter?

Comment: Could the dependency be resolved with `x = func.execute(x);`?

Comment: Passing x and returning the changed value sounds like the most logical solution for me

Comment: Witch type of dependency between Block A and Block B ??

Comment: I think for us to be able to help as best as possible, you need to provide a better example. Something much closer to reality.

Comment: Passing the variable as a parameter solved my issue, I don't know why it didn't occur to me before. Thank you a lot!